# How to put 2 correlation matrices on the same page in landscape?

Tags: tables, landscape

I am trying to fit 2 correlation matrices on the same page on a landscape format. Here is what I use:

```
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering \caption{Correlation matrix, group 1\label{corrtable}}
\begin{tabular}
.....
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering \caption{Correlation matrix, group 4\label{corrtable}}
\small
\begin{tabular}
...
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
```

I obtain 2 pages: one correlation table on each page. I'd like to have them both on the same landscape page. 
Thanks for any help,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: And in addition: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: try the [H] specifier with float package